# Image upload and show using nodejs backend, angular frontend and mysql db

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I try to save and retrieve an image using MySQL database, node.js and angular. but the image couldn't be stored. Please, anyone, help me to solve this.

image upload HTML  file is

```
     <div class="image-container">
                    <label class="hoverable" for="fileInput">
                    <img [src]="user.profile_pic ? user.profile_pic : 'https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png'"> 
                    <div class="background"></div>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <input id="fileInput" type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
<button *ngIf="user.profile_pic" (click)="delete()" >delete</button>
```

onselectFile method is,

```
onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.user.profile_pic = event.target.result;
         this.userService.updateProfilePic(this.user.profile_pic).subscribe(
          res => { 
                            console.log(res); 
          },
          err => { console.log(err); }

        );

      }

    }
  }
```

service file update Profile method is,

```
 public updateProfilePic(profile_Pic:any){
    const params = {
      profile_Pic: profile_Pic,
      email: this.authService.getEmail()     
    };
    const url = `${API_URL}/user/profile_pic`;
    return this.httpClient.put(url, params);
    }
  }
```

database table is,

```
  create table users(
        email varchar(50) primary key,
        name varchar(50),
        address varchar(50),
        tel varchar(10),
        pwd varchar(50),
        privilege boolean default 0,
        profile_pic longblob
    );
```

node.js backend addProfile method is,

```
export const addProfilePic=(req: Request, res: Response) => {

   const update_user_query = "update users set profile_pic=? where `email`=?";

   Mysql.getPool().query(update_user_query, [req.body.profile_pic,req.body.email],(err:any, results:any) =>
      {if (err) {
         console.log("Error", err);
         res.status(500)
            .json({"error": err});
      } else {
         console.log("Result: ", results);
         res.json(results);
      }
   }
   );
 }
```

Comment: Where is the problem?When you debug where you "lose" your image?

Comment: in backend req.body.profile_pic  is capture as undefined